# How to connect my python back end to my HTML front end to create a GUI for Double hashing ? Any other means to create a GUI?

Tags: python, html

This is for my mini project which is evaluated..basically i need a GUI to show double hashing implementation. I used html and css to create my front end but i am not able to connect my back end to the front..

I've written my code in python and the front end part using HTML and CSS

double hash page in html where i need to embed my python code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='style1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
<!--<script src="hash.js"></script>-->
<!-- method i tried to embed my code -->    
<!--<script type="text/javascript">
function runPyScript(input){
var jqXHR = $.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "/double",
async: false,
data: { mydata: input }});
return jqXHR.responseText;}
$('#submitbutton').click(function(){
datatosend = 'this is my matrix';
result = runPyScript(datatosend);
console.log('Got back ' + result);
});
</script>-->
<!-- end of method -->  

<title>DOUBLE HASHING IMPLEMENETATION</title>
</head>
<br>
<br>
<body>
<h1> DOUBLE HASHING</h1>
<!--<h3 class="probingName">Type of Probing: </h3>-->
<div id="container">
<a href="fe.html"><i class="icon-home">Home</a></i><br>
</div>
<br>
<div id="instructions">
<p>Enter the size of the hash table:</p>
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="size" placeholder="size" required>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="ENTER" value="ENTER">
</form>
</div> 

<div id="content">
<br />
<!-- my pyhton code -->     
<% def double_hashing(keys, hashtable_size, double_hash_value %>
<%hashtable_list = [None] * hashtable_size %>
<%for i in range(len(keys)): %>
<% hashkey = keys[i] % hashtable_size %>
<%if hashtable_list[hashkey] is None: %>
<% hashtable_list[hashkey] = keys[i] %>
<% else: %>
<% new_hashkey = hashkey%>
<%while hashtable_list[new_hashkey] is not None: %>
<%steps = double_hash_value - (keys[i] % double_hash_value) %>
<%new_hashkey = (new_hashkey + steps) % hashtable_size%>
<%hashtable_list[new_hashkey] = keys[i]%>
<%return hashtable_list %>


<% values = [26, 54, 94, 17, 31, 77, 44, 51] %>
<%=print(double_hashing(values, 21, 19))%>
<!-- end code -->
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the python package `Flask`, you can set up a web server with an HTML frontend and a python backend in only a few lines of code.

Here is the `Flask` website: http://flask.pocoo.org/

Here is a pretty basic example of a `Flask` server that displays a web page and you can post data to:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def post():
    return "recived: {}".format(request.form)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

note: for `render_template` to work, your HTML file must be in a folder called `templates`

Answer (score -1):

To connect front-end with backend using python you need a backend development framework. popular in python is Django full-stack, flask micro-framework, and pyramid full stack.. create web pages in HTML using all front end technology after that put all in 1 folder but anyway you need a framework for the link. You can use API also but ultimately need a FRAMEWORK.